# How to change font color in semantic UI React Accordion

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I'm currently trying to use the accordion component of Semantic UI React and can't figure out how to change the color and arrow to white.

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html

In the css, you can see that the widget has styling that configures it to black.

1. Does the component have a way to change the text color?
2. Is it possible to put a parent div to override the color text?  (tried
   that but didn't work)
3. How would you override the color? Any workaround. (This can be done with an override as mentioned below in the comments with the !important tag)

The accordion react component takes in panels

```
const panels = [
    {
        title: "test1",
        content: "test1"
    },
    {
        title: "test2",
        content: "test2"
    },
    {
        title: "super",
        content: "test"
    }
]

<Accordion className="test" panels={panels}/>

.test{
   color:white;
}
```

The accordion takes in a className, but passing in a style doesn't seem to work at all either. I've tried at each level as well Accordion.Title Tag.

[image]

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You have to personalized the class of the composant you want to change and you have to "overriding" the css classes of semantic-ui using !important.

```
.ui.accordion.perso
.title:not(.ui) {
     color : #ffffff !important;
}
```

If you want more info on !important (https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Peace

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to do it without !important.  it seems a bit hacky.  Wonder if the component was designed in a way to allow this

Comment: !important is not hacky. It's just want to say that an element has priority than an other element. You have to be carefull and create unique id or class name to use it, like that you change only one element :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
<Accordion>
    <Accordion.Title className="test2">
       <Icon name='dropdown' />
       <label className="label-color"> super</label>
    </Accordion.Title>
    <Accordion.Content>

    </Accordion.Content>
</Accordion>
```

Realized that I could just use the separate components of an accordion and add my own elements and style it.